# Dynamically update newly created label numbers

Tags: jquery

I am creating new divs dynamically with input field and remove button by setting rule as maximum of 5 field can be created. How can I update label text dynamically?

For example, if I click on `+ New` the first time, newly created label should be `Name 1`, and second time, `Name 2` etc. The same should be happened in case of deleting also (values should be updated dynamically)

Though I am trying to get the same by below, its not working as expected...

```
jQuery('.new-label').text('Name ' + x);
```

**[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g57eecpk/1/)**

```
var max_fields      = 5;
var wrapper         = jQuery(".input_fields_wrap");
var add_button      = jQuery(".addNewLink");

var x = 1;
jQuery(add_button).click(function(){
  if(x < max_fields){
    x++;
    jQuery(wrapper).append('<div><span class="new-label">Name</span> <input type="text" name="textfield[]" placeholder="Enter name"> <a href="javascript:;" class="remove_field">x Remove</a></div>');
    jQuery('.new-label').text('Name '+x);
  }
});

jQuery(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(){
  jQuery(this).closest('.form-group').remove();
  x--;
})
```

```html
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <div>
    Name
    <input type="text" name="textfield[]" placeholder="Enter name">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="addNewLink">+ New</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the relevant label when creating the new elements and also update the labels when deleting them, read inline comments

```
var wrapper = jQuery(".input_fields_wrap");
var add_button = jQuery(".addNewLink");

var x = 1;
add_button.click(function() {
    if (x < max_fields) {
        //Create HTML element
        var html = $('<div><span class="new-label">Name</span> <input type="text" name="textfield[]" placeholder="Enter name"> <a href="javascript:;" class="remove_field">x Remove</a></div>');

        x++;

        //Append it
        wrapper.append(html);

        //Update the label
        html.find('.new-label').text('Name ' + x);
    }
});

wrapper.on("click", ".remove_field", function() {
    //remove parent div
    jQuery(this).closest('div').remove();  

    //Relabel them
    var labels = wrapper.find('.new-label');
    labels.text(function(){
        return 'Name ' + (labels.index(this) + 2);
    });
    x--;
})
```

[image: jsFiddle]

Comment: **@Satpal** working like charm... I am **Accepting** your answer.. thanks for your time

Comment: Elegant solution on the renumbering

Answer (score 1):

Instead of updating the text of label after appending it to DOM do update it in the `append()` method and in the remove method there is no such element `.form-group` so you can change it to `div`:

```js
var max_fields = 5;
var wrapper = jQuery(".input_fields_wrap");
var add_button = jQuery(".addNewLink");

var x = 1;
jQuery(add_button).click(function() {
  if (x < max_fields) {
    x++;
    jQuery(wrapper).append('<div><span class="new-label">Name' + x + '</span> <input type="text" name="textfield[]" placeholder="Enter name"> <a href="javascript:;" class="remove_field">x Remove</a></div>');

  }
});

jQuery(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function() {
  jQuery(this).closest('div').remove();
  x--;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <div>
    Name
    <input type="text" name="textfield[]" placeholder="Enter name"> <a href="javascript:;" class="addNewLink">+ New</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this it would be easiest to create a function which updates all the `span` labels when a new `div` is added or removed. This way the numbers in the names are always up to date. Also note that you can negate the need for maintaining the `x` variable by using the current number of `div` elements in the page. Try this:

```js
var max_fields = 5;
var $wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap");
var $addButton = $(".addNewLink");

$addButton.click(function() {
  var fieldCount = $wrapper.find('> div').length;
  if (fieldCount < max_fields) {
    var $div = $('<div><span class="new-label"></span> <input type="text" name="textfield[]" placeholder="Enter name"><a href="javascript:;" class="remove_field">x Remove</a></div>').appendTo($wrapper);
    updateNames();
  }
});

$wrapper.on("click", ".remove_field", function() {
  $(this).closest('div').remove();
  updateNames();
})

function updateNames() {
  $('.input_fields_wrap span').text(function(i) {
    return 'Name ' + (i + 1);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <div>
    Name
    <input type="text" name="textfield[]" placeholder="Enter name"> <a href="javascript:;" class="addNewLink">+ New</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

I delegated both links and removed the ugly javascript:;
I also target the div

```js
var max_fields = 5;
$(function() {
  $wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap");
  $wrapper.on("click",".addNewLink",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var len = $wrapper.find(".new-label").length;
    if(len < max_fields) {
      $wrapper.append('<div><span class="new-label">Name '+(len+1)+'</span> <input type="text" name="textfield[]" placeholder="Enter name"> <a href="#" class="remove_field">x Remove</a></div>');
    }
  });  
  $wrapper.on("click",".remove_field", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
    $wrapper.find(".new-label").each(function(idx) {
      $(this).text("Name "+(idx+1)); // more elegant to use .text(function(){}) than .each
    });
  });
 });
```

```css
body{margin:50px;font-family:verdana;font-size:13px;}
div{margin-bottom:15px;}
a:hover{text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <div>
    Name <input type="text" name="textfield[]" placeholder="Enter name"> <a href="#" class="addNewLink">+ New</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi **@mplungjan**, thanks for the answer, but while removing numbers are not updating though :(